# How strong is the analogy between spectra and abelian groups?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

I am led to understand that spectra are some kind of $\infty$-analogue of (discrete) abelian groups, or perhaps more accurately, some kind of generalisation of chain complexes of abelian groups. How strong is this analogy?

Please feel free to assume I know not much more than the definition of spectrum (more specifically, Lurie's definition) and next to nothing about (stable) homotopy theory.

Comment: Pretty strong, for any ring, like $\mathbb Z$, there is an Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum $H\mathbb Z$ which will be a nice ring spectrum. It is a theorem of Shipley that $H\mathbb Z$ module spectra are Quillen equivalent to chain complexes of $\mathbb Z$ modules, which means that they are the same in a homotopy theoretic sense. Thus, the entire category of spectra can be seen as an enlargement of the category of chain complexes.

Comment: If you could expand on that with references, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here's the reference for Shipley's result: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209215 .  She proves more than what I said, including results on dg algebras, and not just dg modules. In order to understand this, one needs to be familiar with model categories.

Comment: Could you please tell me on which page is the definition of spectra in Lurie's book?